# How to attach a volume to a Bluemix strong-pm container

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, strongloop

How can you attach a volume to a container built from the default IBM Bluemix strong-pm image?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create a volume in Bluemix. Use the following command to create the volume:

```
$ cf ic volume create <volume-name>
```

Then you can create a new container and mount the volume, the example below assumes you created a volume named `my_volume` and you want to mount to `/mnt`:

```
$ cf ic run -v my_volume:/mnt --name mycontainer registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-node-strong-pm
```

Run `cf ic inspect mycontainer` to see details of volume mounted.

Comment: Is there a specific path you should mount the volume too? This question is specific to strong-pm based containers. I've tried your instructions mounting it to ` /home/strong-pm/` but then my container doesn't seem to start, getting stuck in the networking phase and eventually shutting down.